# what does it exactly mean that "MongoDB doesn’t have full single server durability"?

Tags: mongodb

I understand the ACID properties of databases, and [durability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_%28database_systems%29) is the guarantee that the data will survive databases crashes.

But I don't understand what "single server durability" means? Does MongoDB have multiple-server durability then?

Comment: MongoDB is now single server durable and has been since v1.6: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Comment: But I want to know "how" -- that is how was it not single server durable previously, and what does "single server" mean here?

Comment: Single server is a single computer, this comes down to network topology. Normally a database like MongoDB would be spread across 10's, 100's maybe even thousands of computers (facebook has 32k+ database shards). Single server durability is important for those that don't need that huge cluster. It is a case of making sure that if that one server crashes or dies there is a way to ressurect the database and it's data and OPs.

Comment: As for how, that page will tell you and it has links at the bottom to blog posts for further information, most specifically this: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/mongodb-single-server-data-durability-guide/ which is old but still...

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about this [blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/381927266/what-about-durability) from 2010. This refers to [Journaling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling) (from 1.8+)

Comment: Yea something around there, been doing a bit more looking it seems 1.7.5 was the key one but that was a dev release so that'd make 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB did not use to have single server durability. However, since journalling is on by default (since 2.0), this is no longer the case. Before journalling, you had to have more than one node in order to make sure that your data was safe, and actively check that it was accounted for in all the nodes.